# On showing the existence of a Markov chain's steady state distribution

Tags: markov-chains, steady-state

I want to show that the Markov chain with such transition matrices written below has a unique stationary distribution $\mu$.

For a space dimension of 6 : 
$$\begin{equation}
\Pi^{(6)} = \begin{pmatrix}
   a_1 &  a_2 &  a_3 &  a_4 &  a_5 &  b_1 \\
   a_1 &  a_2 &  a_3 &  a_4 &  a_5 &  b_1 \\
   a_1 &  a_2 &  a_3 &  a_4 &  a_5 &  b_1 \\
   0 &  a_1 &  a_2 &  a_3 &  a_4 &  b_2\\
   0 &  0 &  a_1 &  a_2 &  a_3 &  b_3\\
   0 &  0 &  0 &  a_1 &  a_2 &  b_4\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$
or for a space dimension equal to 7 : 
$$\begin{equation}
\Pi^{(7)} = \begin{pmatrix}
   a_1 &  a_2 &  a_3 &  a_4 &  a_5 & a_6 &  b_1 \\
   a_1 &  a_2 &  a_3 &  a_4 &  a_5 & a_6 &  b_1 \\
   a_1 &  a_2 &  a_3 &  a_4 &  a_5 & a_6 &  b_1 \\
   0 &  a_1 &  a_2 &  a_3 & a_4 & a_5 &  b_2 \\
   0 &  0 &  a_1 &  a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & b_3 \\
   0 &  0 &  0   &  a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & b_4 \\
   0 &  0 &  0   &  0 & a_1 & a_2 & b_5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

with $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \  0 < a_i < 1$ and $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \  0 < b_i < 1$

I know I can solve the linear system $\Pi \mu = \mu$ in order to solve this problem.

However I would like to know if from the specific "structure" of this matrix, one can say if there is or not a steady distribution ? Is there a direct way to see that this Markov Chain is aperiodic and irreductible ?

Indeed, I would like to extend this to a greater space dimension Markov process with a similar transition matrix and therefore solving $\Pi \mu = \mu$ would lead to very long computations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can view the transition matrix as a graph and analyze its connectivity.
For a transition matrix $\Pi \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, let $G=(V,E)$ be the directed graph where $V = [n]$ and $E = \{(i,j) \in [n]^2 : \Pi(i,j) > 0\}$.

The Markov chain is irreducible if and only if $G$ has one strongly connected component. Again, there are linear-time algorithms for checking this condition. More simply for the matrix above, we can see that all nodes $i > 1$ can directly reach node $i-1$. Moreover, node $1$ can transition to any node. Therefore, the graph has one strongly connected component and thus is irreducible.

An irreducible Markov chain is aperiodic if and only if $G$ has a node with period 1. In this case, it is even easier because every node has a self-loop since $\Pi(i,i) > 0$ for all $i \in [n]$.

It follows from the fundamental theorem of Markov chains that $\Pi$ has a unique stationary distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I changed the question in order to explain more on the "structure" of the matrices. In the general case I don't think that the argument to prove the irreductiblity holds. Does it ? Moreover, considering the self-loop argument to prove the aperiodicity, does this means that the period of the matrix is d=1 ? and therefore this is why it is not periodic ?

Comment: Yes, one strongly connected component is essentially the definition of irreducibility: It is possible to get to any state from any other state.

The period of a matrix is a different property than the period of a state in a Markov chain, so no. To see why a self-loop leads to aperiodicity for irreducible Markov chains, from any starting node you can reach the node with a self-loop, cycle on that node as much as you want (to break the period), and then return to the starting node.

Comment: I got the argument for the aperiodicity thank you. However in the general case of the matrices I am studying, there are no strongly components : the argument on vertex 3 does not hold I think, does it ?

Comment: I misread the matrix at first so you're right about the earlier argument being incorrect. I updated my post with a correct argument about irreducibility.

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you mean "the graph is one strongly connected component" ? Did you mean "has" instead of "is" ?

Comment: Yes, I changed the text to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok I see. What you meant, which is maybe even more clear, is simply that the graph is strongly connected no ? Regards

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's essentially the same definition as irreducibility.